# how to change custom UIImageView when table view cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

i am using custom cell with uitableview . In cell i have one uiimage and a lable .when i am loading table view that time i am loading all unselected image in custom cell . now i want when user tab a cell at that time want to change image (selected image). after that its going in an other view contoller but when user coming he can see selected cell with selected image icon.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];

    title=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hi one ", @"one ",@"one ACCOUNT ",@"one A SEVICE",@"one YOUR ORDER",@"one FREE SERVICE",@" one WALL",@"one POINTS", @"one LOCATOR",@"one WITH US",@"one_ PACKAGE",@"one_call",nil];



    imgicon=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"profile_icon.png",@"db_icon.png",@"ma_icon.png",@"pickup_icon.png",
             @"ic_track_nav.9.png",@"rf_icon.png",@"wal_icon.png",@"ic_loylty_nav.9.png",@"ic__locator.9.png",@"ic_nification.png",@"kage_icon.png",@"ic_reachus.png",nil];


    imgiconselected=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"profile_icon.png",@"db_icon_p.png",@"ma_icon_p.png",@"pickup_icon_p.png",
                     @"ic_track_nav.9_p.png",@"rf_icon_p.png",@"wa_icon_p.png",@"ic_loya_nav.9_p.png",@"ic__locator.9_p.png",@"ic_notification_p.png",@"pge_icon_p.png",@"ic_reacs_p.png",nil];

    [slidertb reloadData];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // here how can i get that cell path and icon image to change .
    NSLog(@"row==%ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    if(indexPath.row==1){

        FroVC *froVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"froVC"];
        UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        [navController setViewControllers: @[froVC] animated: NO ];
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
    }



}
```

Comment: why dont u use `UIButton` it has diff states and according to thta u can change the image

Comment: can you explore it . i am not getting you

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected` method for your UITableViewCell. Inside this method you can change your ImageView according to `selected` state.

If you want this changes while user didn't release finger from cell you can use `- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted` method.

**UPD.** Example:

```
// code inside your UITableViewCell.m
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
  [super setSelected: selected];
  _myAwesomeImageView.highglighted = selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // Get cell here, which index path cell image you need to change

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// set image for selected state

[cell setImage:[UIImage ImagedName:@"imageName"]];

}
```

OtherWise in place of image you can take UIButton and change the state of button as same, we are changing the image on Image view in above code.